# JClouds 1.5 to 1.6 upgrade - org.jclouds.blobstore.BlobStoreContextFactory class no longer exists

Tags: jclouds

Upgrading jclouds from 1.5 to 1.6 and the class `BlobStoreContextFactory` is no removed

We used to have some unit test code with

```
    BlobStoreContextFactory contextFactory = new BlobStoreContextFactory();
    BlobStoreContext blobStoreContext = contextFactory.createContext("transient", "identity", "credential");
```

But it can't compile anymore.

```
[ERROR] /Users/davsclaus/workspace/camel/tests/camel-itest-osgi/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/itest/osgi/jclouds/BlobStoreBlueprintRouteTest.java:[27,28] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class BlobStoreContextFactory
[ERROR] location: package org.jclouds.blobstore
```

I could not find any migration guide etc from the 1.6.0 release notes from: http://jclouds.incubator.apache.org/documentation/releasenotes/1.6/

Any pointers how to create a `BlobStoreContext` without the factory or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. There is a new `ContextBuilder` API to be used.

```
BlobStore blobStore = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("transient").credentials("identity", "credential")
                          .buildView(BlobStoreContext.class).getBlobStore();
```

Comment: There's also a full example at https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/blobstore-basics/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/blobstore/basics/MainApp.java See L93-101